# Is it possible to use IDEs other than PyCharm for remote debugging AWS Glue scripts?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, pyspark, pydev, aws-glue

I couldn't find any information or examples on this. Is it possible use other IDEs such as Visual Studio, IntelliJ Idea or Eclipse for this purpose? AWS documentation only focuses on PyCharm, Zeppelin, and Jupyter Notebook/SageMaker, however, neither of them is an option for me.

Comment: For Eclipse PyDev see https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Comment: Can I add Jetbrains' dataspell to your list?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ (Professional) and I think VSCode now support Glue via [Interactive Sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions.html) that allow remote development.  Install the Big Data Tools plugin for IntelliJ ... the same plugin as is used for PyCharm.

You'll be prompted for a suitable profile from your `~/.aws/config` or ~/.aws/credentials` sources.

In the past, you would need to set up a VPC Endpoint; this is no longer required for Glue 2.0 and higher (current version as of May 2022 is 3.x).